# Is it possible to can-EVENT on scroll with CanJS?

Tags: canjs

In my app, I have a fixed sidebar that can scroll its overflow content vertically.  When I get to the end of the scrollable area, the scroll event bubbles to the main window.  I would like to prevent that bubble from happening.  I've tried a couple things

```
<div id="sidebar" can-scroll="scrollMe">
<div id="sidebar" can-onscroll="scrollMe">
```

I have the scrollMe function in my component's scope, but neither one of the above options binds.

How do I bind to scroll event, or is it even possible using a can-EVENT?

Comment: scroll events do not bubble. This is why you can't use jQuery's event delegation to listen to scroll events on a parent.  Please create a fiddle showing can-EVENT not listening to scroll and I will check it out.

Comment: Thanks @JustinMeyer.  I found the stupid-simple error in my css code.  The scroll was happening on a parent container.  So it's not a CanJS problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was my mistake.  The can-scroll event works.  My CSS code was set up to allow scrolling on the parent element.

So the simple answer is yes, it's possible to use can-scroll.